# Store an array in drupal 7 field

Tags: 7, entities

I have an use-case where a large associative array is getting generated while saving a node. The array is for a specific content type. I want to save the array along with the node.

While saving all the values of an array to different fields is not practical; Should I parse the array and save it as a string to a certain field so that I can get the array back while fetching?

If so, which one would be better : serialize or json_encode.

While I heard serialize is not reliable all the time, json_encode's purpose is not the same what I am going to use.

Briefly, **I want to store a dynamic associative array against a node.**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`serialize` is better for small array, cuz `unserialize` will work faster. So if you work with huge data use `json_encode` &`json_decode`.
[Comparison PHP Serialization vs JSON Encoding for an array](http://blog.shozab.net/php-serialization-vs-json-encoding-for-an-array/)  and your question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574728/serialize-or-json-in-php) on `stackoverflow` you can find more information about your question.

Comment: Define small array

Comment: The first link 404's. :(